# How to get right attribute which contain "&" through libxml2

Tags: c, libxml2

When I try to get the attribute of URL in a test XML:

```
<Test> <Item URL="http://127.0.0.1?a=1&b=2"/>
</Test>
```

After I call: attr=xmlGetProp(cur, BAD_CAST "URL");

The libxml2 give a message: Entity: line 1: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'

and return value of attr is "http://127.0.0.1?a=1=2"

How can I get the completion attribution of URL? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get the “correct” URL here because the XML file is not *well-formed*. the `&` should have been written as `&amp;`. You have to ask the creator of the XML file to create a *syntactically valid, well-formed XML file*.

XML is *not* created by just putting strings together, they also have to be encoded properly.